# Faster Paint on Flex Mobile

Tags: android, touch, flash-builder, draw

I am trying to build an app that tracks touchpoints and draws circles at those points using Flash Builder. The following works perfectly, but after a while, it begins to lag and the touch will be well ahead of the drawn circles. Is there a way of drawing the circles that does not produce lag as more and more of them are added?

In declarations, I have:

```
    <fx:Component className="Circle">
        <s:Ellipse>
            <s:stroke>
                <s:SolidColorStroke alpha="0"/>
            </s:stroke>
        </s:Ellipse>
    </fx:Component>
```

And this is the drawing function:

```
            var c:Circle = new Circle();
            c.x = somex;
            c.y = somey;
            c.fill = new SolidColor(somecolorint);
            c.height = somesize;
            c.width = somesize;
            c.alpha = 1;
            addElement(c);
            c = null;
```

Comment: Do you want a trail of circles created, or do you just want a circle constantly under each touchpoint?

Comment: I should add that I'm doing the paint on ontouchmove and ontouchbegin events, if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try taking a look at doing a fullscreen [Bitmap](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Bitmap.html) created with a [BitmapData](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html) class. As the touch points are moved, update the bitmap data at the coordinates where the touch occured. Modifying and blitting a screen-sized bitmap is extremely fast and will probably work great for what you're trying to do.

Another performance trade off often done is to make a series of lines instead of continuous circles. You create a new line segment only when a certain distance has been traveled, this lets you limit the number of nodes in the segment thereby keeping performance high.

Comment: thank you! I'll read a bit more on bitmaps and get back to you with questions :)